# Create an array with a specific field

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

My array return this:

```
Array ([0] => stdClass Object ([term_id] => 44 
                               [name] => Escritórios comerciais 
                               [slug] => escritorios-comerciais 
                               [term_group] => 0 [term_order] => 1 
                               [term_taxonomy_id] => 44 
                               [taxonomy] => area 
                               [description] => 
                               [parent] => 33 
                               [count] => 0) 
       [1] => stdClass Object ([term_id] => 45 
                               [name] => Escritórios de advocacia 
                               [slug] => escritorios-de-advocacia 
                               [term_group] => 0 
                               [term_order] => 2 
                               [term_taxonomy_id] => 45 
                               [taxonomy] => area 
                               [description] => 
                               [parent] => 33 
                               [count] => 0) 
       [2] => stdClass Object ([term_id] => 46 
                               [name] => Sede administrativa 
                               [slug] => sede-administrativa 
                               [term_group] => 0 
                               [term_order] => 3 
                               [term_taxonomy_id] => 46 
                               [taxonomy] => area 
                               [description] => 
                               [parent] => 33 
                               [count] => 0) 
       [3] => stdClass Object ([term_id] => 47 
                               [name] => Alimentação 
                               [slug] => alimentacao 
                               [term_group] => 0 
                               [term_order] => 4 
                               [term_taxonomy_id] => 47 
                               [taxonomy] => area 
                               [description] => 
                               [parent] => 33 
                               [count] => 0) 
       [4] => stdClass Object ([term_id] => 48 
                               [name] => Indústria 
                               [slug] => industria 
                               [term_group] => 0 
                               [term_order] => 5 
                               [term_taxonomy_id] => 48 
                               [taxonomy] => area 
                               [description] => 
                               [parent] => 33 
                               [count] => 0 ))
```

Is possible to create an array only with 'slug' field without using `array_column`?

Comment: Can you please edit the code it is nearly unreadable, put it on more than one line at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a foreach to iterate through the outer array and then just index the inner one directly.

```
$slugs = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $slugs[$key] = $value->slug;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work with `array_map`:

```
$result = array_map(function($v) { return $v->slug; }, $array);
```